# Response JSON Request

Tags: c#, json, vb6, webrequest, webresponse

I am trying to use JSON .NET with a WebRequest, to retrieve JSON using "GET". Essentially, I am stuck on the parsing part and grabbing the item to test. The WebResponse, how would I go about retrieving the JSON file using the webResponse? The API.php is a way for me to connect to a website database to login. If the login is successful, it returns a JSON object.

```
            string sAddress = "http://hitsparkinteractive.com/api.php";

            // Get the hash
            string addrParams = "action=authenticate";
            addrParams += "&username=" + user;
            addrParams += "&password=" + pwd;

            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(sAddress + "?" + addrParams);
            webRequest.Timeout = 3000;
            WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

            JObject retJSON;
            retJSON = JObject.Parse(webResponse.ToString());
```

This is working code from Visual Basic 6, that uses WinHTTPRequest.

```
Private Function AuthenticateUser(ByVal index As Long, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As Long
     Dim HTTP As WinHttpRequest, sAddress As String, addrParams As String
     Dim JSONParser As Object, retJSON As String, ErrorCode As String, ErrorMsg As String

 On Error Resume Next

 sAddress = "http://hitsparkinteractive.com/api.php"

 addrParams = "action=authenticate"
 addrParams = addrParams & "&username=" & Username
 addrParams = addrParams & "&password=" & Password

 Set HTTP = New WinHttpRequest
 HTTP.Open "GET", sAddress & "?" & addrParams, False
 HTTP.SetTimeouts 250, 250, 250, 3000
 HTTP.Send

 retJSON = HTTP.ResponseText
 Set HTTP = Nothing

 ' Parse your JSON here.
 Set JSONParser = JSON.parse(retJSON) ' What is returned is Scripting.Dictionary object
 If Not JSONParser Is Nothing Then
    If JSONParser.Exists("error") Then  ' keys are case sensitive I believe
        ' We errored out
        ErrorCode = JSONParser.Item("error")

        Select Case ErrorCode
            Case "3"
                AuthenticateUser = 1

            Case Else
                AuthenticateUser = 2
        End Select

        ErrorMsg = JSONParser.Item("message")
        Call AlertMsg(index, ErrorMsg)
        Exit Function
    ElseIf JSONParser.Exists("hash") Then ' we got our hash, sucessfully authenticated
        TempPlayer(index).Hash = JSONParser.Item("hash")
        AuthenticateUser = 0
        Exit Function
    End If
Else
    AuthenticateUser = 3
    Call AlertMsg(index, "Request timed out, please try again.")
    Exit Function
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
// Get the hash
string addrParams = string.Format("action=authenticate&username={0}&password={1}", user, pwd;)
string url = string.Concat(sAddress, "?", addrParams);

HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Timeout = 3000;

using (HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {

        DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyTypeJsonResponse));
        object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());

        //json parsing response
        MyTypeJsonResponse response = objResponse as Response;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyTypeJsonResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "myProperty2")]
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "myProperty2")]
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is actually a string, representing serialized objects.

`ToString` returns a string representation of an object -- probably something like `System.Web.HttpResponse`.

What you need is the text of the response, and that you can get via the [`GetResponseStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.getresponsestream(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).